# How do I make an animation with only 3rd and 1st View Controllers on swift while dismissing both the 2nd and the 3rd VCs?

Tags: swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uiviewanimationtransition

Good evening!

I'm new on programming and I'm trying to make a swift application that goes like this:

A --segue--> B --segue--> C

I´m using modal segues between the view controllers.

Then I want to go back from the third view controller to the first one and I'm currently using the following code:

C ---dismissCandB---- > A

```
self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

I´m not using NavigationController on this app so any code trying to solve this issue envolving Navigation Controller settings won´t help me.

The problem is: I wanted an animation involving only the third and the first view controllers (just like a modal segue from C to A). But I can't use the segue because in order the app to work properly I need to pass data from C to A through delegates (and not prepareforsegue).

When I set the boolean value to "true", the animation always involves the second view controller, and I don't want it to be shown.

Any ideas on how can I make this work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dharmesh! This piece of code actually did the trick. But now I have another issue that is keeping me from implementing that code. The data that I was passing from C to A through delegate is not passing anymore. A is starting like if I was just starting the app for the first time. Any Ideas on how to fix this. Or any other way to make this animation without killing the delegate protocol? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you want to pass just values then check this sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=82406939138568179480

Comment: Thanks a lot Dharmesh, but that would need lots of change on the code. Actually when I use dismiss the 1st VC appears with the changes I've made on it before the segue. When I use Instantiate it appears as new, which is not the point. So what I´m trying to do now is create just before the segue B--->C a new View on B on top (with the visual of the 1st VC) so when I dismiss, the cross dissolve method will make the same visual effect as if the 2nd VC wasn't being show.  Any hints on how can I make this happen? Thanks a lot.